# Partly object update

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

How to partly of update the object?

For example create object "project":

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '
{ "name":"Project 1", "number": 123 }
' localhost:8080/myapp/projects
{
  "id" : 79,
  "number" : "123",
  "name" : "Project 1",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/myapp/projects/79"
    },
    "project" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/myapp/projects/79"
    }
  }
}
```

And update this project:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '
{ "number": 124 }
' localhost:8080/myapp/projects/79
{
  "id" : 79,
  "number" : "124",
  "name" : null,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/myapp/projects/79"
    },
    "project" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/myapp/projects/79"
    }
  }
}
```

The property "name" now is null.
How to set old-value object property if this property not set in update request?

I'm use @RepositoryRestResource annotation for ProjectRepository to direct Spring MVC to create RESTful endpoints at /projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: use PATCH http method.

```
curl -i -X PATCH -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '
{ "number": 124 }                    
' localhost:8080/myapp/projects/79
{
  "id" : 79,
  "number" : "124",
  "name" : "Project 1",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/myapp/projects/79"
    },
    "project" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/myapp/projects/79"
    }
  }
}
```